# Decrease margin sublime distraction-free mode

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I just discovered the wonder of distraction-free mode in sublime text. However, I've noticed that the left hand margin is really large, making the code start halfway through the screen. Here's a picture of what I mean:

[image: Picture of my sublime]

Is there a way to make it so the code starts more towards the left of the screen?

Answer (score 4):

If you open the default settings for Distraction Free mode (under the Preferences menu), you'll see that one of the options is

```js
"draw_centered": true
```

Open the Distraction Free User preferences and set

```js
"draw_centered": false
```

and you'll be all set. Remember, any setting that appears in your Default or User Preferences can be set in Distraction Free mode as well.

Comment: Weird, when I open my distraction free mode preferences there's nothing written inside.

Comment: Also when I try save any text I get `Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Distraction Free.sublime-settings:1:16`

Comment: Oh I had to surround the preference with curly brackets and it works!